# Pitch shifting/Time stretching in Android with Superpowered

Tags: android, audio, superpowered, pitch-shifting

I need to extract audio from video and pitch shift it at real-time by changing pitch with seekbar([something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpAB.png)). 
Performance need to be near real-time. 
At now at least I need to pitch shift audio(someone .aac audio file).
I found an Superpowered library, but examples dont implement pitch-shifting and docs not contain info about it.
Did anyone do it? Or maybe can help me with another libs?

I am found this [example](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/issues/256) and 
at now I am trying to do it:

```
bool NDKAudioPlayer::process(short *output, unsigned int numberOfSamples) {
double masterBpm = player->currentBpm;

bool silence = !player->process(stereoBuffer, false, numberOfSamples, volume, masterBpm);

if (!silence){
    handler = new LiveTimeStretchingHandler();
    setupLiveTimeStretching(handler, currentSamplerate);
    liveTimeStretchingProcess(stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples, 0, handler);
    delete handler;
}

// The stereoBuffer is ready now, let's put the finished audio into the requested buffers.
if (!silence) SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt(stereoBuffer, output, numberOfSamples);
return !silence;
```

}

This is my NDKAudioPlayer class:

```
class NDKAudioPlayer {
public:

NDKAudioPlayer(unsigned int samplerate, unsigned int buffersize, const char *path, int audioFileOffset, int audioFileLength);
~NDKAudioPlayer();

bool process(short *pInt, unsigned int numberOfSamples);
void onPlayPause(bool play);
void onCentsChanged(int cents);

private:

SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO *audioSystem;
SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *player;
LiveTimeStretchingHandler *handler;
float *stereoBuffer;
float volume;
int currentSamplerate = 0;
```

};

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe this help someone with the same problem:**
I have implemented it with setPitchShiftCents method of SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer class.
This method make pitch shifting while playing audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PlayerExample](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform/tree/master/Examples_Android/SuperpoweredPlayer) project and add two lines at the beginning of the audioProcessing callback:

```
player->setTempo(1.0, true); // Needed for the pitch shifting to work
player->setPitchShift(-12); // Pitch shift one octave down
```

Comment: These functions do not exist in the latest SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h file. instead use: ```player->setPitchShiftCents=(int value from -2400 to 2400)```